# Gmail and Yahoo access using Tor

Tags: configuration, anonymity, email

I used the firefox add-on "Export Import Cookies" to import cookies and logs into email accounts like gmail and yahoo with Tor Browser 6.5 successfully, but that does not work in Tor Browser 7.05. In Tor Browser 7.05 I tried the "cookie Wizard with Witelist" add-on for import cookies and although cookies are imported, websites behave as if cookies do not exist and I can not get into my email accounts. I can not use a phone number to login because that breaks my anonymity. I need to import some cookies to enter the email accounts using different IPs because without those cookies the security of the email prevents the login if the IP is not the same used in the creation of the account. I do not understand why cookies are successfully imported by the "Cookie Wizard with Whitelist" but Tor Browser and the sites behave as if cookies were never imported. I can see imported cookies in "preferences> privacy> Show Cookies," but the sites can not find them. I tested the same add-on on firefox-esr 52.3.0, which is the basis of Tor Browser 7.05, and I was able to import cookies and log in to email accounts normally. Can anyone tell me how to import cookies using Tor Browser 7.0.5? Does anyone have any other ideas on how to access yahoo and gmail email accounts using Tor Browser?
Thanks any ideas.
Sorry about the bad english.

Comment: In private browser mode extensions/addons no longer have access to cookies and add-ons aren't supported.

Comment: @canonizingironize, that is not the case because I disable de private mode ever, I never use the Tor Browser with private mode enabled. I ever uncheck "Always use private browsing mode" in "preferences>privacy". My browser run in a ramdrive, so if my computer shutdow all my private data vanishes, so I do not care about stored history, that is not dangerous for me. I copy a configured Tor Browser to ramdrive every time I run it. Even with private mode disabled, my add-on do not work, the cookies are imported but the browser behave as if that never happens.

Comment: Right, Tor Browser also patches how cookies are handled for private data also enjoy destroying your anonymity by changing the private browsing mode setting. And once again, *add-ons aren't supported*.

Comment: Private mode is neither important nor useful to me because, as I said, my browser runs in a ramdrive, all browsing data is lost when I turn off the computer. The private browsing mode is stupid because when the browser breaks I lose my whole session, that's why I do not use it. I turn off private browsing mode and set to Never Accept third party cookies, and check if my setting is good on sites like "http://ip-check.info" and the result is identical to the original Tor Browser setting.

Comment: I use tor browser in linux behind a transparent tor proxy without flash and no java installed, so I do not mind installing some extensions in the browser, this is not a threat to me because I already take some precautions. It is true that the tor browser is not meant to install extensions, however I install some extensions that work very well. As I said, the extension worked on earlier versions of the tor browser with the same configuration, which is why I asked if anyone knew a solution to the new problem.

Comment: "*the result is identical to the original browser setting.*" those tests are heuristic and you can likely be fingerprinted through supercookies or cache between uses of new identity.

Comment: "*this is not a threat to me because I already take some precautions*" it is if your need long-term unlinkability.

Comment: "you can probably be fingerprinted through supercookies or cache between uses of new identity". That's why I do not leave my Tor Browser on disk, in addition it is completely deleted every time I finish using it or want to change identity. Supercookies or cache can not survive this.

Comment: Right but New Identity also wouldn't work properly.

Comment: New identity for what?
I do not need the "New Identity" option in Tor Browser if I delete the existing Tor Browser and replace for a new one every time I want to use a "New Identity".